# Split row based off of row value in a previous column (2 patterns) - incorrect values using tstrsplit

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit

I am attempting to move the values of the Structural Notation column to a new column named either SMILES or InChI based off of the value in the Structural Notation Type column. Essentially, I want all SMILES notations in the Structural Notation column to be in the SMILES column and all InCHI notations in the Structural Notation column in the InCHI column.

In order to reach that conclusion, I had created the Combine column where I combined the contents of the Structural Notation Type column and the Structural Notation column and add either a " && " or " %% " for the SMILES and INCHI row values respectively.

```
library(data.table)

structures <- structure(list(CAS = c("70024-85-0", "80934-44-7", "356-86-5",
"70024-86-1", "79004-87-8", "63335-88-6", "70024-79-2", "28994-41-4",
"63021-86-3", "63041-90-7"), `Structural Notation Type` = c("SMILES",
"SMILES", "SMILES", "SMILES", "SMILES", "INCHI", "SMILES", "INCHI",
"INCHI", "INCHI"), `Structural Notation` = c("", "", "O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C",
"", "", "1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3", "",
"1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2",
"1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H",
"1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H"
), Combine = c("SMILES && ", "SMILES && ", "SMILES && O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C",
"SMILES && ", "SMILES && ", "INCHI %% 1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3",
"SMILES && ", "INCHI %% 1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2",
"INCHI %% 1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H",
"INCHI %% 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Rendered

```
         CAS Structural Notation Type
 1: 70024-85-0                   SMILES
 2: 80934-44-7                   SMILES
 3:   356-86-5                   SMILES
 4: 70024-86-1                   SMILES
 5: 79004-87-8                   SMILES
 6: 63335-88-6                    INCHI
 7: 70024-79-2                   SMILES
 8: 28994-41-4                    INCHI
 9: 63021-86-3                    INCHI
10: 63041-90-7                    INCHI
                                                                                Structural Notation
 1:                                                                                                
 2:                                                                                                
 3:                                                                       O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
 4:                                                                                                
 5:                                                                                                
 6:                                                1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
 7:                                                                                                
 8:                                1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
 9:                  1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
10: 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H
                                                                                                     Combine
 1:                                                                                               SMILES && 
 2:                                                                                               SMILES && 
 3:                                                                      SMILES && O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
 4:                                                                                               SMILES && 
 5:                                                                                               SMILES && 
 6:                                                INCHI %% 1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
 7:                                                                                               SMILES && 
 8:                                INCHI %% 1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
 9:                  INCHI %% 1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
10: INCHI %% 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H
```

In the second step, I used the tstrsplit split function from `data.table`. You will see that the end result is not correct. For example, you'll see in row 3 which is a SMILES row and should be in the SMILES column is actually in the InCHI column.

```
structures[, c("SMILES", "InChI") := tstrsplit(Combine, c("&&", "%%"), fixed = TRUE)][]

structures <- structure(list(CAS = c("70024-85-0", "80934-44-7", "356-86-5",
"70024-86-1", "79004-87-8", "63335-88-6", "70024-79-2", "28994-41-4",
"63021-86-3", "63041-90-7"), `Structural Notation Type` = c("SMILES",
"SMILES", "SMILES", "SMILES", "SMILES", "INCHI", "SMILES", "INCHI",
"INCHI", "INCHI"), `Structural Notation` = c("", "", "O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C",
"", "", "1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3", "",
"1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2",
"1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H",
"1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H"
), Combine = c("SMILES && ", "SMILES && ", "SMILES && O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C",
"SMILES && ", "SMILES && ", "INCHI %% 1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3",
"SMILES && ", "INCHI %% 1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2",
"INCHI %% 1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H",
"INCHI %% 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H"
), SMILES = c("SMILES ", "SMILES && ", "SMILES ", "SMILES && ",
"SMILES ", "INCHI ", "SMILES ", "INCHI ", "INCHI %% 1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H",
"INCHI "), InChI = c(" ", NA, " O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C", NA,
" ", " 1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3", " ",
" 1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2",
NA, " 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Rendered

```
          CAS Structural Notation Type
 1: 70024-85-0                   SMILES
 2: 80934-44-7                   SMILES
 3:   356-86-5                   SMILES
 4: 70024-86-1                   SMILES
 5: 79004-87-8                   SMILES
 6: 63335-88-6                    INCHI
 7: 70024-79-2                   SMILES
 8: 28994-41-4                    INCHI
 9: 63021-86-3                    INCHI
10: 63041-90-7                    INCHI
                                                                                Structural Notation
 1:                                                                                                
 2:                                                                                                
 3:                                                                       O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
 4:                                                                                                
 5:                                                                                                
 6:                                                1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
 7:                                                                                                
 8:                                1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
 9:                  1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
10: 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H
                                                                                                     Combine
 1:                                                                                               SMILES && 
 2:                                                                                               SMILES && 
 3:                                                                      SMILES && O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
 4:                                                                                               SMILES && 
 5:                                                                                               SMILES && 
 6:                                                INCHI %% 1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
 7:                                                                                               SMILES && 
 8:                                INCHI %% 1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
 9:                  INCHI %% 1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
10: INCHI %% 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H
                                                                                     SMILES
 1:                                                                                 SMILES 
 2:                                                                              SMILES && 
 3:                                                                                 SMILES
 4:                                                                              SMILES &&
 5:                                                                                 SMILES
 6:                                                                                  INCHI
 7:                                                                                 SMILES
 8:                                                                                  INCHI
 9: INCHI %% 1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
10:                                                                                  INCHI
                                                                                               InChI
 1:
 2:                                                                                             <NA>
 3:                                                                        O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
 4:                                                                                             <NA>
 5:
 6:                                                 1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
 7:
 8:                                 1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
 9:                                                                                             <NA>
10:  1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H
```

Is there a way to avoid creating the Combine column and move each row matching SMILES into the SMILES column and move each row matching the INCHI column into the InCHI column directly?

If not, is there a way to avoid the errors that are appearing with the use of tstrsplit?

@Wimpel, thank you for your answer. I have included both a Preferred and an Ideal Solution below.

This is the **Preferred Solution**

```
           CAS Structural Notation Type
 1: 70024-85-0                   SMILES
 2: 80934-44-7                   SMILES
 3:   356-86-5                   SMILES
 4: 70024-86-1                   SMILES
 5: 79004-87-8                   SMILES
 6: 63335-88-6                    INCHI
 7: 70024-79-2                   SMILES
 8: 28994-41-4                    INCHI
 9: 63021-86-3                    INCHI
10: 63041-90-7                    INCHI
                                                                                Structural Notation
 1:
 2:
 3:                                                                       O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
 4:
 5:
 6:                                                1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
 7:
 8:                                1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
 9:                  1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
10: 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H
                                                                                                     Combine
 1:                                                                                               SMILES &&
 2:                                                                                               SMILES &&
 3:                                                                      SMILES && O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
 4:                                                                                               SMILES &&
 5:                                                                                               SMILES &&
 6:                                                INCHI %% 1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
 7:                                                                                               SMILES &&
 8:                                INCHI %% 1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
 9:                  INCHI %% 1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
10: INCHI %% 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H
     SMILES                                                                                
1: 
2: 
3: O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
4: 
5: 
6: 
7: 
8: 
9: 
10: 

                                                                                            
InChI
1: 
2: 
3: 
4: 
5: 
6: 1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
7: 
8: 1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
9: 1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
10: 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H
```

This is the **Ideal Solution** (where the Combined column is not needed to be created in the first place)

```
           CAS Structural Notation Type
 1: 70024-85-0                   SMILES
 2: 80934-44-7                   SMILES
 3:   356-86-5                   SMILES
 4: 70024-86-1                   SMILES
 5: 79004-87-8                   SMILES
 6: 63335-88-6                    INCHI
 7: 70024-79-2                   SMILES
 8: 28994-41-4                    INCHI
 9: 63021-86-3                    INCHI
10: 63041-90-7                    INCHI
                                                                                Structural Notation
 1:
 2:
 3:                                                                       O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
 4:
 5:
 6:                                                1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
 7:
 8:                                1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
 9:                  1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
10: 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H

     SMILES                                                                                
1: 
2: 
3: O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
4: 
5: 
6: 
7: 
8: 
9: 
10: 

                                                                                            
InChI
1: 
2: 
3: 
4: 
5: 
6: 1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
7: 
8: 1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
9: 1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
10: 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H
```

---

**UPDATE:**

This is the correct solution offered by @Wimpel.

```
> dcast(structures, CAS ~ `Structural Notation Type`, 
+       value.var = "Structural Notation", fill = "")
           CAS
 1: 28994-41-4
 2:   356-86-5
 3: 63021-86-3
 4: 63041-90-7
 5: 63335-88-6
 6: 70024-79-2
 7: 70024-85-0
 8: 70024-86-1
 9: 79004-87-8
10: 80934-44-7
                                                                                              INCHI
 1:                                1S/C13H12O/c14-13-9-5-4-8-12(13)10-11-6-2-1-3-7-11/h1-9,14H,10H2
 2:
 3:                  1S/C16H9NO2/c18-17(19)14-9-7-12-5-4-10-2-1-3-11-6-8-13(14)16(12)15(10)11/h1-9H
 4: 1S/C20H11NO2/c22-21(23)20-16-7-2-1-6-14(16)15-10-8-12-4-3-5-13-9-11-17(20)19(15)18(12)13/h1-11H
 5:                                                1S/C10H22/c1-4-5-6-7-8-9-10(2)3/h10H,4-9H2,1-3H3
 6:
 7:
 8:
 9:
10:
                       SMILES
 1:
 2: O=C(OCC(F)(F)C(F)(F)F)C=C
 3:
 4:
 5:
 6:
 7:
 8:
 9:
10:
```

Comment: You mentioned errors from `tstrsplit`, what errors are you seeing? (The only one I see is a _warning_ about `Invalid .internal.selfref detected`, which stems from the fact that `structure(..., class=c("data.table","data.frame"))` always needs to be wrapped in `as.data.table(.)` (or `setDT(.)`) so that the local copy can gain the needed memory buffers afforded by `data.table`. The `structure(...)` along is incomplete internally, not a fault of R's `dput`.

Comment: @r2evans In this case, I was referring to a different meaning of "error". From Wiktionary, "The state, quality, or condition of being wrong. " (See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/error#English). I was stating that the result from `tstrsplit` was wrong.

Comment: No need to quote a dictionary or wiktionary, you just need to state the distinction. Most questions on SO that mention error reference an `Error:` or `Warning:` condition, as in a _signal condition_. The fact that a question is being asked usually means something is incorrect, so I suggest "being wrong" is an assumption going in. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like casting to wide format should work... Since your sample data is lacking desired output, it is hard to check if this solution works for you..

```
dcast(structures, CAS ~ `Structural Notation Type`, 
      value.var = "Structural Notation", fill = "")
```